# Как присвоить элементу вектора значение переменной?

Tags: c++, xcode, vector

Имеется вектор,

```
vector<string> Vector[2];
```

имеется строка,

```
string String = "bla-bla-bla";
```

при вот таком дейтвии:

```
Vector[0] = String;
```

выдает ошибку.

Comment: Приведите, пж-та, логи ошибки - без этого очень сложно диагностировать проблему

Answer (score 3):

Вот это `vector<string> Vector[2];` - не вектор, а массив из двух векторов (пустых).

Т.е. `Vector[0] = String;` - это попытка присвоить строку вектору строк.

Если нужен вектор из двух строк, нужно писать `vector<string> Vector(2);` (круглые скобки вместо квадратных). Тогда все будет работать.